# Array Expansion prototype cause the stimulsoft report can not be display

Tags: asp.net, charts, reportviewer, stimulsoft

When i want to display my mrt report  using following code in ascx

```
<cc1:StiMobileViewer ID="StiMobileViewer1" ShowDesignButton="false" runat="server" />
```

and following code in .cs

```
 StiReport report = new StiReport();
 report.Load(Server.MapPath(CRMResources.DynamicReportResources + "ChartForBillTest.mrt"));
```

StiMobileViewer  show nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found out that I should upgrade to new version of stimulsoft 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the report to the Viewer.

```
StiMobileViewer1.Report = report;
```